# Why does the matching query does not exist error occur?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There is a model:

```
class ProductRating(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            UniqueIndex(fields=['user', 'product']),
        ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.BooleanField()
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created_time')
```

I want to create a row in the database with a post request

```
class PostRatingFromUser(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductRating.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrAuthenticatedUser, ]
    serializer_class = ProductRatingSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rating_from_db = ProductRating.objects.get(product_id=kwargs['pk'], user=request.user)
        if rating_from_db:
            rating_from_db.grade = kwargs['grade']
            rating_from_db.save()
        else:
            ProductRating.objects.create(product_id=kwargs['pk'], grade=kwargs['grade']).save()
        return Response(status=200)
```

But before adding, I check if there is such a database, if there is, then I just change the value of 'grade'

but it gives me an error:

```
product.models.ProductRating.DoesNotExist: ProductRating matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is django's default behaviour.

> If get() doesn’t find any object, it raises a Model.DoesNotExist exception:
> (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get)

If a query cannot get a record, e.g: Product Rating, django returns an error.

I think you might want to look into this instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Otherwise, you need to catch the error like this:

```
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name="John", last_name="Lennon")
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Person(first_name="John", last_name="Lennon", birthday=date(1940, 10, 9))
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need pass **`product__id`** like this...

```
ProductRating.objects.get(product__id=kwargs['pk'], user=request.user)
```